# Layout for panel with unknown size

Tags: java, jpanel

I have a jpanel which I don't know its size 
(It will be determined by the user)

I want to place M labels in the panel (M is determined in run time)
such that each label will be centered and its width will be 90%.
The height will be absolute..
(between every 2 labaels there will be seperate line)

Hot do you suggest to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it with a Y_AXIS oriented [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html). You can use [JSeparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JSeparator.html) for lines.

Comment: Thanks. how can i set the width of a label to 90% in that case?

Comment: Not an elegant solution, but you can listen to component resize events and set component sizes. If this looks ugly to you, you have two more alternatives: 1)develop a custom layout manager 2)develop a custom component and paint everything.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `GridLayout(0, 1, 0, horizGap)` -- the 0, 1 for 1 column, variable number of rows, the next 0 for vertical gap, which you don't need, and the horizGap for the horizontalgap between rows.

Then place it in another JPanel that is padded on the right left via an EmptyBorder.